# What diplomacy effect do I receive when liberating the last city of a different civ?

Tags: civilization-5

Basically, a civilization has only one city left, which it has conquered from someone else. What would happen if I liberated the city, essentially wiping out the civ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well,logically that would mean you will both get a warmonger penalty and lose some of it.I really believe that the warmonger penalty would be higher,though,so do it at your own risk.